# Remove the last link in a div, but keep the "link" text - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am building some breadcrumbs for a nav. This is done before the page is rendered via a templating language. Once the page is rendered, I need to do some figuring.

Instead of doing a bunch of IF/ELSE on the templating side, is there a way to render a div with links.. lets say..

```
<div id="bc_links">
<a>Link one</a> >
<a>Link 22</a> >
<a>Link 33</a> >
<a>Link 44</a> >
</div>
```

THEN do some jquery or prototype (have access to both libraries) and be able to identify that link44 is the last link, and make the display this:

```
<div id="bc_links">
<a>Link one</a> >
<a>Link 22</a> >
<a>Link 33</a> >
 Link 44
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.innerWrap()` to wrap the text in a `<span>` tag, then select the new `<span>` tag and `.unwrap()` it, removing the anchor tag from the DOM and keeping the text intact.

```
$('#bc_links').children().last().wrapInner('<span />').children().unwrap();
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dB8R/

### Update

You can also use `.contents()` to remove text-nodes (the caret at the end of the line):

```
$('#bc_links').contents().last().remove();
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dB8R/1/

Comment: Impressive chaining. Although the text remains wrapped in the `<span>`

Comment: @DidierGhys Yeah that was by design. `<span>` tags won't change the display of the content unless you set their CSS properties to do so and it makes it so much easier to work with elements if they are wrapped in something. It's almost certainly better for performance to just replace the `<a>` tag with a text-node rather than wrap/unwrap.

Comment: I agree. I'm still amazed by the line anyway ^^

Comment: @DidierGhys This one's for you (this will also remove the trailing caret): `$('#bc_links').children().last().wrapInner('<span />').children().unwrap().parent().contents().last().remove();`

Comment: wow - a little over my head.. but why add the "wrapInner" in there, what does it enable you to do? I am missing how that fits in here.

Comment: @jamesemanon If you run a `.replaceWith()` to get rid of the `a` tag you have to get the text of the anchor before replacing it so you can add it to the new element. If you wrap and unwrap the text remains untouched.

Comment: ok.. but when I look at this code: 
$('#seobc').children().last().wrapInner('<span />').children().unwrap('a');
$('#seobc').contents().last().remove();

How are you getting rid of the trailing " > " ?

Comment: @jamesemanon In order to select comment or text nodes with jQuery you need to use the `.contents()` function. It returns all children of an element, including comment and text nodes. So `$('#seobc').contents().last().remove();` selects all the children of the `#seobc` element (including comment and text nodes), then refines that set of elements to only the last one using `.last()` (intuitively I know this is a caret since I know the structure of the HTML, hopefully...), then `.remove()` removes that element from the DOM.

Comment: @jamesemanon Check the `tagName` property of the element: `$('#bc_links').contents().each(function () { var tagName = this.tagName.toLowerCase(); })`. The `.toLowerCase()` is nice because some browsers use uppercase and some use lower (most use upper). Here are some good docs on `tagName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName

Answer (score 5):

```
var $link = $('#bc_links a').last();
$link.replaceWith($link.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bc_links a:last').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to place each  tag within an unordered list (li).

```
$("li").last().find("a").unwrap();
```